# Как различаются по смыслу выражения «я хочу» и «мне хочется»?

Tags: грамматика, семантика

Семантика таких предложений **сходная**,  они отражают одну и ту же ситуацию. Речь идет **о  желании**, которое испытывает определенный субъект, но разные **смысловые  оттенки,** очевидно, присутствуют.

А вот **грамматическая форма**  в этих вариантах  отличается существенно: мы имеем или двусоставное, или односоставное безличное предложение.  Считается, что в **безличном** предложении описываются процессы, неподконтрольные человеку, происходящие сами собой. Но  разве можно  **контролировать** свои желания и управлять ими? Скорее всего, в этом плане ситуация одна и та же, то есть "бесконтрольная", но мы ее изображаем **различным образом**.

И вопрос: Можно ли определить, в чем заключается **разница смысловых оттенков** и как это отражается на выборе той или иной **грамматической формы**?

Comment: Ну "это мне хочется" это банальный пассив(переворот) от "я хочу это". Тут нет ничего интересного. А вот в чем отличие: "мне подойти?" от "я подойду?" это интересно

Comment: Ну вдалбливать понимание я не нанимался.

Comment: Ладно, буду иметь в виду.

Comment: "Мне подойти" - только вопрошающая враза. "Я подойду" - и вопрошающая, и утверждающая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, выражение "я хочу" определяет чёткое осознанное желание индивида. "Мне хочется" - напротив, идёт не от той части сознания, которым человек управляет, а от тех отделов, которые он не контролирует.

Comment: Да, мне нравится ваше решение;  кроме того, в словаре  также указано различие:  хотеть – это иметь желание,  а хотеться – это ощущать желание. Я еще могу добавить несколько слов про безличную форму, которая позволяет нам обозначить эти семантические оттенки.  Сначала мы называем неосознанное ощущение (это единая форма для всех лиц – хочется, хотелось), а потом уже указываем  а д р е с а т а, то есть кому хочется. Этот адресат и  есть   с е м а н т и ч е с к и й    с у б ъ е к т   в форме Д.п., о котором здесь недавно говорилось.